# Update existing test cases blocked in xRay importer

Tags: csv, jira-xray

I want to update the action, expected result, and description of existing Xray test cases with the xRay importer feature but the import is each time blocked infinitely.

[image: blocked in xray tests importer]

[image: log of xray importer blocked]

test cases identifier, summary, Jira issue key are all in the header of my CSV and are all mapped already else I wouldn't be able to start the import.

Even if I try to stop the import that will be stopping infinitely.

And after this issue, I tried a new creation of a test having only mandatory fields and it is the same problem also.

> Update: It sounds that it is not blocked but instead it is **slow** in a blocking way

Comment: Are you using Xray on Jira cloud or Xray on Jira server/datacenter?

Comment: Jira server/datacenter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the request is taking too long. This can be due to many reasons, including your Jira server/DC overall infrastructure, its setup, etc. Xray being the cause is probably not the case as test cases are usually simple entities.
I'm unsure whether...

- this problem is systematic
- ou have many (thousands?) test cases being imported
- if you're importing specific fields for the tests that may have some logic implemented in Jira side
- whether you have some sort of complex workflows on top of Test issues (or any other integrations implemented on Jira related to them)

Just some points for you to consider.
At first, I could recommend also you to try simpler and fewer test cases to see if the problem is connected to that.

Overall, there's not much we can do from here except recommending you to reach out [Xray support team](https://jira.getxray.app/servicedesk/customer/portal/2), so you can provide them logs and other internal information that may be needed to diagnose this in further detail.

Comment: Yes, sounds from server/DC overall infrastructure the issue is gone after restart.